# How do i create a class library proejct to handle my migrations and database objects in entity framework core 2.2?

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.2

I have created a .net core 2.2 web mvc application. I then created a .net core 2.2 class library to contain all my database models. When attempting to run the initial migration i get the error cannot create object of type 'X'.

I have referenced my class library in the main web project, set it as the startup and in the package manager console i set the default project as the class library.

I expected this to create my migrations but i get this error.

```
public class ProjectWalesDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectWalesDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectWalesDbContext> options)
     : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Course> UserCourse { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(b => b.created_at)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
           .Property(b => b.password_reset_date)
           .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
          .Property(b => b.password_reset_required)
          .HasDefaultValueSql("0");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
          .Property(b => b.course_progress)
          .HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    }
}
```

this is my db context that i set up ive set it up the same way in other projects so i cant see what ive done wrong if anything. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I needed to add the line:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectWalesDbContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

to the start-up of the web app so I could create the context.